# Why do people use comments as a business logic

Tags: coding-style, business-logic

Why do people rely on comments as business logic ? (example CakePHP, Doctrine)

Doctrine example (from their docs, doctrine is relying on the comments as much as the code itself):

```
/**
 * @Entity @Table(name="products")
 **/
class Product
{
    /** @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;
    /** @Column(type="string") **/
        protected $name;
...
```

A few weeks ago I had to do a change in a CakePHP app and I had a problem where a callback was not called, only digging deep in their guts I found out that I need to put a docblock comment before the function definition for it to be recognized an called, I was in sock. Unfortunately I don't have the code now to give you an example.

I used many programing languages, but I find this trend that I only saw in PHP to be very annoying, and I think breaks the rules of programming.

Maybe somebody can shed some light on it, in my opinion this is a very bad practice, but I look forward to hear you opinion.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a relatively easy way (nice or not) to bring third party respectively new functions to a programming language without cause compiler errors. But you are right search for errors is  sometimes annoying.

Comment: @Radu Maris
Would be nice if you can leave some comment/upvote/accept answer to signal if answer was helpful or not. The question itself is very interesting but unfortunately with little attention :-/

Comment: I was expecting more insides, for large projects it's a debugging hell, but this is true for everything that has some kind of "magic" it's easy to use them on simple projects, but you go to hell and back if you step off the magic path and you need custom stuff or you need to squeeze more performance. As the question is old and not active I accepted your answer.